React Framer Scroll Space
I want something like Horizontal Scroll Carousel at https://www.hover.dev/components/carousels but when you scroll to the last image I want to remove the extra space and end the container with the last image. How do i do this?
I played with the width but was unsuccessfully. Is there anyway to do this with the CSS?
